The "Cookie Settings" link in the footer is not aligned vertically with the other links in the "Company" section on narrow screens
When the width of the browser window that is displaying a site on the Stack Exchange network is sufficiently wide, it shows the different sections in the footer (e.g. the "Meta Stack Exchange", "Company", and "Stack Exchange Network" in columns, e.g. (at 900 px wide):



Once the width of the window gets sufficiently narrow (e.g. when browsing on a mobile device), the responsive design of Stack Exchange sites results in the columns being displayed horizontally, as tables, e.g. (at 700 px wide):



Now, the "Cookie Settings" link in the "Company" section is clearly at not aligned with the other links:



This appears to affect all Stack Exchange sites (based on a small sample size: Meta Stack Exchange, Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Super User, Meta Super User, Server Fault, and Meta Server Fault), whether or not I'm logged in, and regardless of the browser/operating system (reproduced on Firefox 125.0.3 on Windows 11, Chrome 124.0.6367.119 on Windows 11, and Chrome 124.0.6367.113 on Android 14).
Presumably this is due to the "Cookie Settings" link actually activating a modal as opposed to being a regular link.
Could this be fixed please?
